# Django JSON De-serialization Security

Tags: python, django, json, security

Are there any known security vulnerabilities with Django's JSON deserializer? Regarding Python deserializing protocols, the general concensus seems to be they're completely insecure, so avoid parsing untrusted data.

However, I'm considering a distributed web application where different servers exchange model records, formatted as JSON. The records themselves don't contain sensitive data, but I'm concerned about the ability for a hacked server breaching another server by sending maliciously formatted JSON. Is this possible?

I usually see Django's JSON serializer in public-facing environments, so I would hope it's hardened against this kind of thing, but I haven't been able to find any documentation addressing any security issues.

Comment: Are you enabling CSRF protection? That should go a long way towards ensuring security.

Comment: What is "maliciously formatted json"?

Comment: @Marcin, JSON formatted to exploit some vulnerability in the parser, allowing execution of arbitrary instructions on the server.

Comment: @Cerin I know what malicious formatting is. I am asking you to provide an explanation or example of what maliciously formatted JSON would be.

Comment: @Marcin, I'm essentially asking if such a thing exists. If I had an example, I wouldn't need to ask :)

Comment: @Cerin: That's not what you're asking. If you want to ask that question, then ask that question. In any case, it behoves you to actually learn about the format to understand how this might be possible.

Comment: @Marcin, I'm sorry you didn't understand my question, but there's no need to be rude.

Comment: @Cerin The only thing I see here as rude is your accusation that there is something rude in what I have said. If you don't think it behoves you to learn about the formats that you use, then that's your loss.

Answer (score 4):

By default when using [simplejson](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), which is the default deserializer used by Django, the types of objects that can be converted from JSON into a Python object are limited. The only way this is not the case, is if you're doing some kind of specialized decoding utilizing the optional arguments to the [`loads()`](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#simplejson.loads) or [`load()`](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#simplejson.load) methods or your own [`JSONDecoder`](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#simplejson.JSONDecoder) object.

So, as long as you're using default decoding, you're pretty safe. But, if you're really concerned, you should be validating the loaded JSON data BEFORE you actually do anything with it.

Comment: OK, this is a very nice, over-general advice: "validate the loaded JSON" - what do I validate it with? Regular expressions? Check if size less than X? Pickle is unsafe by design, because it can call constructors of arbitrary objects, and JSON is quite passive. However, history knows cases like this one: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2013/01/31/what-the-rails-security-issue-means-for-your-startup/ (this was actually because of using a too general parser: not JSON specific). We cannot rest completely assured without very heavy fuzzing such a parser.

Answer (score 3):

I'm having trouble working out what you think could be insecure (or secure) about JSON.

JSON is a text-based data exchange format. It doesn't have any security built-in. Django comes with some functions to serialize and deserialize querysets to JSON. But these can't be "malicious" or "insecure" - they're just data.

Some serialization protocols, eg pickling, can potentially be insecure because they can contain code, so could possibly be deserialized to run something that harms your system. Serialized models don't have that problem, because they don't contain code.

Of course, if you were using JSON to (for example) pass a list of model IDs to be deleted, then there is the potential for a malicious user to include a whole load of IDs you don't want deleted. But again this isn't the fault of JSON - it's up to you to ensure that your business logic correctly determines which elements a user is allowed to delete or modify.

Comment: But if the decoder is flawed then [even](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/17365) [data](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms04-028) [can be](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/security/bulletin/ms04-025) [malicious](http://www.securityfocus.com/bid/51292).

Comment: @Ignacio, Exactly. Plenty of applications that only read data (e.g. image viewers, music players, etc) have occasionally had this kind of vulnerability. I don't want to automatically assume Django is exempt.